# How to scale asp.net mvc app and wcf service independently

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, iis-7, azure, iis-6

I have ASP.NET web apps and 1 wcf web service. I would like to deploy them to Azure so that they can scale out/up independently. i.e. i can give small VM to mvc apps and give big VM & more instances to wcf service. Another requirement is that I need https for web app. However, I don't want to have https from mvc app to wcf service, which causes unnecessary encryption/decryption.

I can deploy each app & wcf service to individual hosted service on Azure so they can scale independently.(so if 3 app + 1 wcf service will have 4 hosted service on Azure) To avoid https between mvc and wcf, i try to use internal endpoint. Unfortunately seems internal endpoint is supported only within one host service.

To avoid https between mvc and wcf, the only way is deploy mvc apps and wcf all in one host service. However, then you loose the possibility to scale independently.

In a summary:

1. if each mvc app and wcf service deploy to its own hosted service, i can achieve independently scaling requirement, however, i cannot avoid unnecessary encryption/decryption between mvc app and wcf service (https)
2. if deploy apps and wcf service all in one host service. I can use internal end point between app and wcf to avoid https encryption/decryption. However, you loose the possibility of scaling independently.

I would like know is there a way can achieve both. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have multiple web roles in a hosted service that can be scaled individually and use internal endpoints between MVC and WCF bits. Alternatively, if the WCF service does not need to be publically accessible you could expose it as a TCP endpoint using ServiceHost in a worker role...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to scale independently by Role, not by Service.  So, deploying WCF as another role within your Service should work fine.  You'll have to think about ports however if WCF need to have external endpoints or load-balancing if WCF is consumed via internal endpoints.

Check out AzureWatch @ http://www.paraleap.com - will get you up and auto-scaling your two roles independently in a few minutes without any code changes.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry maybe i am not using terms so correctly. I know that by deploying WCF & web apps with different web roles can scale independently. However, if I do so, it means apps and wcf service will only be different from port. e.g. app1: xyz.cloudapp.com:80 , app2: xyz.cloudapp.com:81, service: xyz.cloudapp.com:82. However, if I need to have https (port 443) for app1 & app2, as far as i know it is impossible... In addition, wcf need to have both input & internal endpoint. internal endpoint with http to communicate with mvc app to avoid unnecessary encryption/decryption.

Comment: Input endpoint still needs to have https in case of accessing to service directly from internet. So in summary, mvc apps and wcf all need to support https. Is it possible to achieve on one port 443 ..?

Comment: Sounds like you need the WCF service to be exposed externally.  You can still have SSL security over an endpoint even if the port is not 443.  Would this work for you?

Comment: yes. mvc apps need to have https. wcf have both https(input endpoint for external use), http(internal endpoint). probably it should work with a port other than 443. In your previous comment, you mention about load-balancing, does this solution have any impact to load balancing in case i will have multiple instances to apps and wcf services? thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend setting up regular http:80/https:443 for the website on one Role, and a secure public endpoint for WCF on a port other than 443 on a different Role.  This way, you'll have a public WCF load-balanced across all your servers and scaling independently from the MVC site